# Low quality sound Intel HD Audio HP Envy laptop -16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, sound, pulseaudio

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 from an Envy j100sv laptop-fresh installation. I am experiencing low quality and low volume output audio.

`sudo lspci` shows two audio drivers.

```
Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
```

This is unusual as this laptop has good quality (at least far better than the current) while running windows. The windows installation has beats audio if it is of any help.

By searching about similar issues i have already tried opening `alsa` and it had two driver options. The one called HDA Intel PCH was all the way up. After that i installed the `alsa` gui and `pavucontrol` for `pulseaudio`. In `pavucontrol` when sound is played there is a bar moving below it and it says build on analog stereo. I maxed out the audio on this but it is still kinda low and the quality is bad. I would be grateful if you could help me fix this.

Comment: Do you experience the same problem with HDMI audio?

Comment: you mean if I change some setting?